# How can I return an awaited value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I need `test()` to return a player from my db.  I know I can use a callback but how can I make this work with `async` `await`?

```
fun test(): Player {
    launch(UI) {
        val player = async(CommonPool) { MainActivity.database?.playerDao()!!.loadPlayer() }.await()
        return player
    }
}
```

Currently the error is `return is not allowed here`

In `JavaScript` for example I would make `test` `async` then `await` it's result from where it's called.

Comment: Try with `return@launch player`; but remember, you'll have to `await` the launch to return from the method itself. `launch` is async

Comment: @Zoe Thanks but now it says `type mismatch Required Unit Found Player`

Comment: Nvm then. Launch probably doesn't support returning values. Besides, when you launch async like that, you can't return from the method without blocking the thread. You could use `runBlocking` instead of `launch`

Comment: @Zoe Yep. That compiles.  I will try that thanks

Comment: Note that it will block the thread; be careful if you use it on the main thread, or you risk the OS considering it to be timed out.

Comment: @Zoe `runBlocking { async { blockingFunction() }.await() }` is a very silly way to write `blockingFunction()`. Both snippets achieve exactly the same thing and the former doesn't just look more complex, it's executed in a much more complex way, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to run a coroutine on a raw thread. At the very least you must turn an existing thread into one that spins a top-level event loop. You achieve this with a `runBlocking` call on the very top of the thread's call stack (i.e., inside its `run()` method).

On a GUI thread or any other kind of thread that runs an event loop, you need a matching `Dispatcher` that submits coroutines to this event loop. Kotlin already provides dispatchers for Swing, JavaFX, Android etc. In these cases you need to `launch` a coroutine from some existing GUI event handler, like this:

```
myScope.launch {
    val player = test()
    ... use the player ...
}
```

`myScope` must be an object that implements `CoroutineScope` with something like this:

```
override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob()
```

This will give you a way to cleanly cancel all the coroutines running within the same scope, by calling

```
coroutineContext[Job]!!.cancel()
```

My example uses the `Main` dispatcher, which resolves to the GUI thread when you import the Kotlin coroutines library matching your UI framework.

The `test()` function must become a `suspend fun` that temporarily switches the dispatcher to a thread pool for blocking operations. Here's how a basic example could look:

```
suspend fun test() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    MainActivity.database?.playerDao()!!.loadPlayer()
}
```

Finally, note I don't mention `async` at all in this answer. Kotlin's `async` has a very specific purpose, it is not a general facility like in other languages. Its purpose is strictly parallel decomposition, where you decompose a single task into several concurrent subtasks.

Comment: Thank you.  Is `Dispatchers` new in Kotlin as I have `1.2.61` and get `Unresolved reference`

Comment: Yes, this answer uses the official coroutines API.

Comment: Sweet.  I will upgrade and take your advise.  I'll get back here later and mark the answer as correct if it helps me.

Comment: Turns out I'll need to refactor my code a little for the 1.3.0 Coroutines but I will respond to your answer once I have.  Probably a day or so.